# MongoDB: How to count distinct values in arrays while grouping in an aggregation stage

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation pipeline in which I'm trying to find the unique values within an array property and also the number of instances of each value within each document's array.

I arrive at a stage where the documents look like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("5d8cac657d2d1e0145268fb4"),
    values: [
        "5d8a2c3d4768d9660d3ba383",
        "5d8a1d4f4768d951cb6c8989"
    ]
},
{
    _id: ObjectId("5d8caf4039321e7b14061a46"),
    values: [
        "5d8a2c3d4768d9660d3ba383",
        "5d8c835a39321e7b15792353"
    ]
}
```

and from here I'd like to end up with a result like the following:

```
{
    values: {
        "5d8a2c3d4768d9660d3ba383": 2,
        "5d8a1d4f4768d951cb6c8989": 1,
        "5d8c835a39321e7b15792353" : 1
    }  
}

or 

{
    values: [
        { "id": "5d8a2c3d4768d9660d3ba383", "count" : 2 },
        { "id": "5d8a1d4f4768d951cb6c8989", "count" : 1 },
        { "id": "5d8c835a39321e7b15792353", "count" : 1 }
    ]
}
```

I'm not too concerned with the format of the result, as long as I have the unique values and their counts I can work with it — whatever the most performant approach is is fine. I can get the unique values by using a $group stage with $push and $reduce but I'm not able to also get the counts that way — could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first option you can try this query:

- First `$unwind` the array `values` to be able to get individualy each element.
- Then `$group` to get the count for each element.
- And the re-grouping again but using `_id` as `null` to get all values into one single array. Every element here will be an object with `k` and `v` attributes. That will be used in the next stage.
- Last stage is `$project` to not output the `_id` value (wich in `null`) and to use [$arrayToObject](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/). Using `k` and `v` in the previous stage it created an array with objects valid to be converted into the desired object.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$values"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$values",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "values": {
        "$push": {
          "k": "$_id",
          "v": "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "values": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$values"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/I3lLndJrV2H)

And for the second option you can try this query:

- The same steps as before.
- The re-grouping here is using `$$ROOT` to get the entire object. As here is not needed anything else you can set the object as it is.
- Last stage is `$project` only to not output the `_id` value.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$values"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$values",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "values": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Gc4vjNTxmrO)

Edit: I didn't notice te second example has `id` and not `_id`. If it is relevant you can use [this query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eI2NJXe7Isn) instead which is the same but instead of using `$$ROOT` to set the entire object at it is, it create the `id/count` object.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`$facet`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) as it allows you to:

> Processes multiple aggregation pipelines within a single stage on the same set of input documents.

While not an overly complex query it means you can `$unwind` and `$group` in the same `$facet` with the output of the sub-pipelines added to a `values` array like so:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      values: [
        {
          $unwind: "$values"
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$values",
            count: {
              $sum: 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RZJnAXBfvG4) for a working example.